# Getting header values, Status code etc from Jax-Rs Response class in Junit

Tags: java, junit, jax-rs, dropwizard

I am using Restful web Service using Dropwizard. And generating response as:

```
    Response response = resources.client().resource("/url")
    .header("CONTENT-TYPE","value")
    .post(Response.class, jsonRequestString);
```

Now I want to write unit test to ensure the returned content type is corrected in Response Object. how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ClientResponse](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html) type in Jackson. For example, using a GET operation:

```
ClientResponse response = Client.create()
                                .resource(url)
                                .get(ClientResponse.class);
String contentType = response.getHeaders()
                             .getFirst("Content-Type");
System.out.println(contentType);
```